# References for Bayesian and Neural networks

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, bayesian-networks

What are the best tutorials you found so far about Neural and Bayesian networks?

I don't need books but, instead, some basic introduction to understand and use related libraries.

Comment: Can you be more specific about libraries that you are interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tutorials from Andrew Moore are a very good -- and not too heavy -- introduction to machine learning topics: http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/. There is a tutorial for both neural networks and Bayesian networks.

Answer (score 1):

My text for this sort of stuff in school was 'Pattern Classification' by Duda, Hart, and Stork.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of bayesian networks called [JavaBayes](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~javabayes/), I consider a good software, read the doicumentation provided at the site.